# Gradle: trouble writing output: excess write of 4

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After recent upgrade of Android Studio we started seeing this message from dex:

"trouble writing output: excess write of 4"

Anyone seeing it? Any ways to resolve this? Currently a clean rebuild helps, but it's annoying to have to that over and over

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `preDexLibraries` set to `false` in your gradle build file? I always do clean builds and I found pre-dexing to be a useless step. However upgrading from android sdk build-tools from 19.1 to 21.1.1 introduced this "excess write" error so I turned pre-dexing back on and the build succeeds. Try re-enabling pre-dexing if you have disabled it.

Comment: I do, yes. However with Android Studio 1.0.1RC the error has disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Nuking `build` directories solved this for me.